# Windows mklink links and Mac

Tags: mac, windows, filesystem

On a Windows AD Server, I have a made a mklink /d to a different file system shown a directory and this all appears to link up nicely for PCs on the network, but the Mac's are unable to follow the link.

How can the Mac follow these links?

On the PCs, I had to run "fsutil behavior set set symlinkevaluation R2R:1" as one the linked file system is to a NAS drive. But I am unable to get to any linked directory on the Mac - NAS or standard RAID.

Is this a just a Mac issue or what is the way around this?

Comment: What if you create an Alias **on** a Mac and place it in that directory? Is that an acceptable solution?

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/387266/119271

Answer (score 0):

We drop an Alias in the same place as windows shortcuts if you can’t make a symbolic link. That lets all clients have a native way to cross navigate folders.

Connect to the share from any Mac and drop the alias using Finder.

That’s a one time process if we protect that file from deletion or just train people to recreate a proper alias it whenever it goes missing.